# WSO2 Identity Server: How to handle Android App login with Google

Tags: android, authentication, wso2, google-signin, wso2-identity-server

Currently, we have the following landscape: a back-end (Play + Scala) server that provides a RESTful API. In addition we have a front-end Web client and an Android native app client. Now we want to add the WSO2 Identity server (v 5.1) to maintain user logins everywhere.

The problem that I am facing is with the native android app integration. I have a successful Google Sign In and as a result I have the Open ID token. According to https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth I should send the token to my back-end server (WSO2IS) where the token should be verified against Google authorities and if the token is legit, it should sign in my user in WSO2IS. Note that if such user doesn't exist in our system, it should first be created and then signed in. Unfortunately I don't find a way to send the token to WSO2 Identity Server.

What I have done so far:
1) configured Identity Provider (IDP Google Federated Authenticators)
2) configured Service Provider where Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration points to previously defined Federated Authenticator Google
3) configured some claims in both IDP and SP

Then I start playing with the endpoints:
**/oauth2/token**
**/oauth2/authorize**
But using this is not what I want, because these endpoints will generate me a new token instead of getting the one I have.

Then I found out about Open ID prompt=none (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest), and I also tried to invoke authorize and pass the open ID connect as Authorization: Bearer <token> header when I call
 **oauth2/authorize?prompt=none&scope=openid&client_id=fzOPC3fCftkgC3xcLn7ZqjXiY_Ya&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9443%2Fcommonauth**

Also tried **none+login**.

Is it possible to do this with WSO2IS? To register/login a user by passing a Google Open ID token?

If it turns out what I am trying to do is not possible, I come up with the following workarounds:
1) Create a custom service that will validate the token and if legit will register a new user. This is just an idea, I don't know if it is possible and also if I need to write the code myself why should I use the WSO2 Identity Server?
2) In the Android App I should drop the native Google sign in support and use a WebView where we will use the pretty clear and standard Web App flow. I cannot evaluate what I will lose by using web view instead of the API, but it seems wrong. It is natural that on Android phone you should sign in seamlessly with your Google account.

If I need to use one of the workarounds, please advise me which one is the better approach? Or propose a new one.

**EDIT 1**: Workaround 2 discarded based on

> Browser popups is the preferred way for web apps to redirect the user to the IdP. Mobile apps on platforms such as Android or iOS should launch the system browser for that purpose. Embedded web views are not be trusted, as there’s nothing to prevent the app from snooping on the user password. User authentication must always occur in a trusted context separate from the app’s context (e.g. the browser).

This is taken from http://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect#auth-request

If it is not possible to use a WebView (for security reasons) and in Android you can only open the browser, but you cannot command it with `startActivityForResult`. This means that even if the user sign in, the browser won't close automatically and it will hand out there until the user close it. In addition the browser won't tell your app that the user is logged and the app should find out by itself (honestly I don't know how: you cannot do server push or something similar, because you can sign in with the same Google account on multiple devices; and the second obvious option is server polling but the app doesn't know for which user to ask).

**EDIT 2**: A new view over things

When configuring Google for a Web Client login, there is a field for authorized URI (the callback that Google invokes to send the token back). For WSO2IS, this is https://localhost:9443/commonauth. So, this should be the URL that we need to  send back the token in the Android app. I start testing with **Postman**, I am sending the following request:
`POST /commonauth?code=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjhhNDJhODMzN2IxMmI5MzI5NGIyNGU5NDY5ZTViZWIwZGFhMWJlNGUifQ.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.VMspUYeaAVHavEyoK3Hsss0pyZMHu-4QozucTAU-CLXnjAoaFbPBirslX7VpS4wvwHPge0AE5gHpIzAl1el_ufkhiu2NJn_LKo48Ve3HNj9igjnwD2nW_PGOqlYPoWV5UtFlKyUxi72qvLOCkYwsPuKVzA9irD-vGm3U2U3wBu_OQrJzbhdU9lp3aG4F0tQgQi-NPtEZY7Xgu-Om3qmarByhJYjxBPHEWzuyuQ2F9xY65t0mnd7gVAr2F5_aBHemjVx8V9lQc4eyRFjE3g_9ZgYn9xX9w8TwCXO9VpkdVRdFWQ07RFjFz915FO5KX9x4UNAu6H1Jop9ug5oiVCrmFw HTTP/1.1`

On server side, this result in an error: Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache. In server logs I found:
`DEBUG -  Session data key is null in the request {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
ERROR -  Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}`

I've looked at the code for DefaultRequestCoordinator, it seems I need 2 more parameters: **type** and **sessionDataKey**. I think the type should be set to openid, but how can I get a valid sessionDataKey?

Comment: So if i understand right, you want to signin with google and send the id_token sent by google to the app instead of the one generated by IS?

I think creating a user during signin is totally possible with Just In Time provisioning.  https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Just-In-Time+Provisioning+for+an+Identity+Provider

Comment: Create/login a user in IS by providing a google id_token from a mobile app signin.